# Is there an alternative console for administering websites in IIS6?

Tags: iis-6

I've used many web site hosting services in the past and I've grown very comfortable with the web based site administration tools. Does anyone have a recomendation for a replacement for IIS Managment Console? Perhaps something that would provide a web based interface for administering web sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Remote Administration (HTML) Tool that comes with Windows/IIS to accomplish this.  Microsoft has a couple of relevant articles that cover this topic:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324282
- http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/aae1d311-103e-4b06-8788-e6b0554d7230.mspx?mfr=true